# Conexión de postgres con heroku usando laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, heroku

Hola me podrían ayudar a solucionar este error que me surge al ejecutar el comando:

```
heroku run php /app/artisan migrate
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi archivo .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ggC88sPiwPi/cx5bS0L8WJk3nzWP4bMIA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=ec-21-65-173.come-1.amanaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=d6hef02h1an
DB_USERNAME=dfgicaeswg
DB_PASSWORD=ae947e0cfddd775fd71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

y este es mi config.database 


<?php

$url = parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

$host = $url["ec-21-65-173.come-1.amanaws.com"];
$username = $url["dfgicaeswg"];
$password = $url["ae947e0cfddd775f6bab0e5d71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6"];
$database = substr($url["d6h6nfh1an"], 1);

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql_p'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

      'pgsql_p' => [
      'driver'   => 'pgsql',
      'host'     => $host,
      'database' => $database,
      'username' => $username,
      'password' => $password,
      'charset'  => 'utf8',
      'prefix'   => '',
      'schema'   => 'public',
   ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

y al realizar la migración desde la raíz del proyecto me vota este otro:

Comando : `php artisan migrate`

Error:

```
C:\Telegram\Database>php artisan migrate
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ec2-23-21-65-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: ec2-23-21-65-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 5
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dfgicaihxreswg in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: dfgicaihxreswg in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 6
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ae947e0cfddd775f69aba8ffbf96e1a7b0e5d71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6 in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: ae947e0cfddd775f69aba8ffbf96e1a7b0e5d71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6 in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 7
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: d6hea6nf02h1an in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: d6hea6nf02h1an in C:\Telegram\Database\config\database.php on line 8

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)

  at C:\Telegram\Database\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\Telegram\Database\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=ec2-23-21-65-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=d6hea6nf02h1an;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "dfgicaihxreswg", "ae947e0cfddd775f69aba8ffbf96e1a7b0e5d71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6", [])
      C:\Telegram\Database\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.

C:\Telegram\Database>
```

Comment: primero que todo estas publicando todo los datos de acceso a tu base de datos recomiendo editar o borrar y volver a preguntar `cuidado!` segundo: esto te puede ayudar [postgre remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku)

Comment: a esque esa es una prueba, quiero ver que conecte nadamas y ya luego aplicar el mismo procedimiento a mi proyecto real

Comment: intenta en el .env pasarle los parametros con comillas dobles en vez de solos!

Comment: Hola, ya intente de ese modo pero no hay ningún cambio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno aqui la solucion  a este error.

debido a que estoy usando botman estudio en mi archivo config.database:

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'ec-21-65-173.come-1.amanaws.com'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'd6h6nfh1an'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'dfgicaeswg'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 
        'ae947e0cfddd775f6bab0e5d71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

y mi .env quedo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]